# Why does city tax value differ between title screen and county screen?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

First image shows that income tax for city Dioclea is 6.85 while second screen shows a value of 6.22.

I was able to calculate city tax value using the formula provided in the [wiki](https://ck2.paradoxwikis.com/Liege_tax) and I got value of 6.22.

Also the values differ for other cities as well but I noticed the difference between these two values is small.

Why is there a difference between the two screens?

Note: I am playing base game without any DLC activated.

[image: Title view]

[image: County view]

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an educated guess then a completly true answer since i can't test it myself at the moment.

When i add together all the taxes you should get from your first image i get a value of 30.2 gold, however the calculated number in the outer list only shows 18.54. Even further when i add all you tax categories together its also short of 1 gold to the 108.19 you should get.

In my opinion this is most likely a visual bug and the numbers there forget to incorporate some modifiers. Another possibility could be, that the gold amounts shown besides the names of the mayors is the full "normal" amount you would get and depending on the color (red, yellow, green, etc.) this amount is in reality either reduced or increased because of modifiers not stated there.